# I am new to JS and I am stuck when trying to bring the user back to the beginning of the program after user clicks OK in confirm

Tags: javascript

I was told to make paper scissors or rock game using javascript. After the user gets to the end of the script, I need to know how to make a function or I think that is what you need when a user clicks "OK" in confirm, the true value will bring the user to the start until the user clicks cancel. But even if I make a function, where would I plug that in? Thank you so much all!

Here is what I have so far...

```js
alert("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game! Press OK to continue");

prompt("Type in P for Paper, R for Rock, Or S for Scissors!")

const storedLetters = ["R", "P", "S"];
const rockPaperScissors = storedLetters[Math.floor(Math.random() * storedLetters.length)]; 

console.log(rockPaperScissors);

var howManyTimesDidYouWin = 0;
var howMayTimesDidILose = 0;
var howManyTimesDidItie = 0;

// Scanner mySccanner = new Scanner(System.in);

if(prompt = "R") {
    alert("1, 2, 3! " + rockPaperScissors);
    if(rockPaperScissors == "R") {
        alert("We have Tied!");
    } else if (rockPaperScissors == "P") {
        alert("Computer has won!");
    } else {
        alert("You have won!");
    }  
} else if(prompt = "P") {
    alert("1, 2, 3! " + rockPaperScissors);
    if(rockPaperScissors == "P") {
        alert("We have Tied!");
    } else if (rockPaperScissors == "S") {
        alert("Computer has won!");
    } else {
        alert("You have won!");
    }
} else if(prompt =="S") {
    alert("1, 2, 3! " + rockPaperScissors);
    if(rockPaperScissors = "S") {
        alert("We have Tied!");
    } else if (rockPaperScissors == "R") {
        alert("Computer has won!");
    } else {
        alert("You have won!");
    }
} 

if (alert = "We have Tied") {
    howManyTimesDidItie++;
} else if (alert = "You have won!") {
    howManyTimesDidYouWin++;
} else if (alert = "Computer has won!") {
    howMayTimesDidILose++;
} 

console.log(`Your total wins are:  ${howManyTimesDidYouWin} and Your Loss are: ${howMayTimesDidILose} and You Tied: ${howManyTimesDidItie}`);

let confirmation = confirm(`Do you want to play again? If Yes, press "OK"! If you do not wish to continue, press "Cancel"`);

//This is where I get stuck! 

// if(confirmation == false) {
//    break;
// } else {
//    continue;

// while(confirmation == true) {
    
// }


// while(confirmation) {
//     continue;
// }

// while(confirmation = true) {
//     continue;
// } 

// var returnToStart = function() {
  //     if(confirmation == true) {
   //        continue; 
  //     } else {
  //         break;
 //   }
```

Comment: Either you put your *whole* program inside a `while (true) {…}` loop, or you put your *whole* program inside a `function game() {…}` where you can call `game()` to restart it. There is no way to slap any statement onto its end that would take you back to the beginning of the code.

Comment: Btw, `=` is assignment, you want `==` comparisons in your `if` conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of refactoring and extracting common logic into functions, you could make the whole program a bit simpler and achieve the repetitiveness that you want.

I've extracted the counts of each situation into constants so that you can easily track the stats.

I've also added repetitive game logic into it's own function which is then used in the logic where the game is running (`runGame()`).

This allows us to reuse the repetitive code. Then, I've put the whole game logic into the `playGame()` function, and finally, the `game()` function is responsible for taking in the player's input and running the whole game in a loop all over again until the player cancels.

```js
let WIN_COUNT = 0;
let LOSE_COUNT = 0;
let TIE_COUNT = 0;

function gameLogic(rockPaperScissors, firstLetter, secondLetter) {
  alert("1, 2, 3! " + rockPaperScissors);

  if (rockPaperScissors === firstLetter) {
    alert("We have Tied!");
    TIE_COUNT++;
  } else if (rockPaperScissors === secondLetter) {
    alert("Computer has won!");
    LOSE_COUNT++;
  } else {
    alert("You have won!");
    WIN_COUNT++;
  }
}

function runGame(input, rockPaperScissors, letters) {
  if (input === letters[0]) {
    gameLogic(rockPaperScissors, letters[0], letters[1]);
  } else if (input === letters[1]) {
    gameLogic(rockPaperScissors, letters[1], letters[2]);
  } else if (input === letters[2]) {
    gameLogic(rockPaperScissors, letters[2], letters[0]);
  }
}

function playGame() {
  alert("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game! Press OK to continue");

  const input = prompt("Type in P for Paper, R for Rock, Or S for Scissors!");

  const storedLetters = ["R", "P", "S"];
  const rockPaperScissors =
    storedLetters[Math.floor(Math.random() * storedLetters.length)];

  console.log(rockPaperScissors);

  runGame(input, rockPaperScissors, storedLetters);

  console.log(
    `Your total wins are:  ${WIN_COUNT} and Your Loss are: ${LOSE_COUNT} and You Tied: ${TIE_COUNT}`
  );
}

function game() {
  let playAgain = true;

  while (playAgain !== false) {
    playGame();

    playAgain = confirm(
      `Do you want to play again? If Yes, press "OK"! If you do not wish to continue, press "Cancel"`
    );
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me! I am understanding how you have placed everything in functions. Can I ask you something? What I am wondering is, how did you plan this out? Like the thought process? If you were told to make this simple program, I am guessing this is how you would have written it. where did you start from when you started to put them in the function. Did you start from playgame()? Thank you once again for letting me pick your brain.

Comment: Yes, of course. First, I look for the code that is repeated and try to split it into a generalised function that can be re-used in more than a single scenario. Then, I try to look at the problem as a whole and look for ways to improve it by splitting it into functions that does one thing only if possible which improves code readability. In other words, I try to apply single-responsibility principles to my functions. When declaring variables, I try to name them in one or two words that convey the meaning of it. Finally, I look at the code again to look for ways of improving it (write less code)

Comment: Actually, `playGame()` was the last function I wrote. I started by splitting the whole logic into different functions and then joined them together. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate different logics into functions you can call individually. In the example below, I created 4 functions: `gameInit`, `gameStart`, `askUser` and `checkResult`.

- `gameInit` resets all stats to zero then starts the game by calling `gameStart`.
- `gameStart` starts the game and saves the results. After this, the user is then prompted if he/she wants to continue playing or whether to reset all stats and play again. Calls `gameInit` for reset, `gameStart` for continue.
- `askUser` prompts the user for his choice, making sure that it is valid. <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> (case-insensitive).
- `checkResult` checks the result using the predefined variable `judge`.

I also tweaked some of your code so it looks a little readable (i.e., removed the too many `if-else`).

```js
const storedLetters = ['r', 'p', 's'];

//store here for easy message formatting.
const rpsNames = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

// yeah, here's the judge that tells you which option
// will beat the one in the right
const judge = {
  'rock': 'scissors', // r beats s
  'paper': 'rock', // p beats r
  'scissors': 'paper' // s beats p
};
// store here so we can easily access using `msgs[result]`
const msgs = {
  tie: 'We have Tied!',
  lose: 'Computer has won!',
  win: 'You have won!'
};

// store results as objects so we can do `results[result]++`
// instead of incrementing different variables using `if-else`
var results = {
  win: 0,
  lose: 0,
  tie: 0
};

function gameInit() {
  alert("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game! Press OK to continue");
  results = {
    win: 0,
    lose: 0,
    tie: 0
  };
  gameStart();
}

function gameStart() {
  let userLetter = askUser();
  let userIdx = storedLetters.indexOf(userLetter);
  let userSelect = rpsNames[userIdx];

  let compSelectIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //randomly select 0-2
  let compSelect = rpsNames[compSelectIdx];

  alert("1, 2, 3! Computer picks " + compSelect);

  let res = checkResult(userSelect, compSelect);

  let msg = msgs[res];
  alert(`${msg} You: ${userSelect}, Computer: ${compSelect}`);

  //update stats
  results[res]++;
  alert(`Your total wins are:  ${results.win} and Your Loss are: ${results.lose} and You Tied: ${results.tie}`);

  let confirmation = confirm(`Do you want to play again? If Yes, press "OK"! If you do not wish to continue, press "Cancel"`);

  if (confirmation) {
    gameStart();
  } else {
    let restart = confirm('Do you want to reset all stats and play again?');
    if (restart) {
      gameInit();
    }
  }
}

function askUser() {
  //make sure use it's not case-sensitive
  var res = prompt("Type in P for Paper, R for Rock, Or S for Scissors!");
  if (res) {
    res = res.toLowerCase();
  }

  if (storedLetters.indexOf(res) === -1)
    return askUser(); //ask again if incorrect selection
  else
    return res;
}

function checkResult(user, comp) {
  if (user === comp) {
    return 'tie';
  }
  var loser = judge[user]; //who loses vs user

  // user beats comp
  if (loser === comp) {
    return 'win';
  } else {
    return 'lose';
  }
}

gameInit();
```